# `pip install cyrptography ` not able to install on python3.7-alpine docker

Tags: docker, pip, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install crypotography using the below dockerfile for alpine3.7 python base.
However, I'm getting error like this:

```
#7 17.27 Failed to build cryptography cffi
#7 17.37 Installing collected packages: pycparser, six, idna, cffi, asn1crypto, pymysql, cryptography
#7 17.68     Running setup.py install for cffi: started
#7 18.04     Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'error'
#7 18.04     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#7 18.04      command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-twxf8fj_/cffi_1f087e9b9e8c4af8b4e6bf3deb3a5bf9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-twxf8fj_/cffi_1f087e9b9e8c4af8b4e6bf3deb3a5bf9/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-j8mkceyt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/cffi
#7 18.04          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-twxf8fj_/cffi_1f087e9b9e8c4af8b4e6bf3deb3a5bf9/
#7 18.04     Complete output (48 lines):
#7 18.04     unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
#7 18.04     unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
```

As per [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#alpine) document I'm installing all necessary packages but still it's throwing me the same error.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR  /project
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo mariadb-dev
RUN pip install pymysql cryptography
```

Can you anyone point me what is i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it can't find the gcc compiler, although it should have been installed by that `apk` command. What does the full log say?

Comment: The examples I see out there that uses `--no-cache --virtual` always runs the build that requires the packages on the same `RUN` command. Maybe if you try `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo mariadb-dev && pip install pymysql cryptography` instead.

Comment: @super still the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -t, --virtual NAME    Instead of adding all the packages to 'world', create a new
> virtual package with the listed dependencies and add that
> to 'world'; the actions of the command are easily reverted
> by deleting the virtual package

> What that means is when you install packages, those packages are not added to global packages. And this change can be easily reverted. So if I need gcc to compile a program, but once the program is compiled I no more need gcc.

> I can install gcc, and other required packages in a virtual package and all of its dependencies and everything can be removed this virtual package name. Below is an example usage:

> ```
> apk add --virtual .dep gcc
> apk del .dep
> ```

So, for you, in `apk add --no-cache --virtual gcc`, the `gcc` was wrongly treat as virtual package name, which means you in fact did not install gcc.

To fix this, try to add a virtual package name before all packages as next:

```
/ # apk add --no-cache --virtual .dep gcc
fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/12) Installing libgcc (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(2/12) Installing libstdc++ (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(3/12) Installing binutils (2.35.2-r2)
(4/12) Installing libgomp (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(5/12) Installing libatomic (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(6/12) Installing libgphobos (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(7/12) Installing gmp (6.2.1-r0)
(8/12) Installing isl22 (0.22-r0)
(9/12) Installing mpfr4 (4.1.0-r0)
(10/12) Installing mpc1 (1.2.1-r0)
(11/12) Installing gcc (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(12/12) Installing .dep (20210629.140945)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r2.trigger
OK: 122 MiB in 47 packages
/ # gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-alpine-linux-musl
Configured with: /home/buildozer/aports/main/gcc/src/gcc-10.3.1_git20210424/configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --build=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --host=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --target=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --with-pkgversion='Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424' --enable-checking=release --disable-fixed-point --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cloog-backend --enable-languages=c,c++,d,objc,go,fortran,ada --disable-libssp --disable-libmpx --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-tls --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.3.1 20210424 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424)
```

Or directly as document said, remove `--virtual`:

```
apk add gcc
```

Comment: thanks. just removing --virtual helped me to build the image. It's new thing to know